# Permalink does not work

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I would like to show Post URLs as http://domain.com/postcategory/postname
So, I entered /%category%/%postname% in the Custom Structure field as in the screenshot below.  However, try clicking the **Hello World!** article here, which goes to 404 page: [Blog Page](http://centurypixel.com/_custom/test.html) **(Password: 444)**

[image: Permalink Settings Screenshot]

Here is the .HTACCESS code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So the final URL should be: http://domain.com/tezhip/hello-world but I just cannot get it work.  Do you guys think it is due to WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

If you'll prefer using plugin to handle the problem, [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-permalink/) plugin should help you fix the problem.